# How to send multiple emails with SendGrid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, sendgrid

The following code seems to work if there is one user, but truncate the email for multiple users:

```
users.each do |user|
  mail(
    :to => user.email,
    :subject => 'Hi',
    :template_name => 'notification'
  ).deliver
```

Is this the proper way to send a few emails?

- Ruby on Rails 3.2.2
- Heroku
- SendGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that each instance of the Mailer can only send one email. Perhaps the mail object is falling out of scope and getting cleaned up by the garbage collector...

The solution that worked was to iterate over the users outside of the Mailer, and call it once for each user. It may be slow but it should happen in the background anyway so it's fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
def my_mailer_method
  users = User.find({ ... })

  headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = { :to => users.to_a }.to_json

  mail(
   :to => "this.will@be.ignored.com",
   :subject => "Hi",
   :template_name => "notification"
  ).deliver
end
```

This sends a message to any number of recipients use the SendGrid's SMTP API.  You can find further information on [the docs page](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/smtp-api/developers-guide/).

You might also want to take a look at the [sendgrid rails gem](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-rails)

Comment: I got `headers` is undefined.

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Check out the Action Mailer docs for details http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#auto-encoding-header-values

Comment: Are you sure you're calling it from within a mailer and not a controller?  As long as you're using ActionMailer it will work

Comment: Yes. Here's the top of the file: `class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => 'Foobar <foo@example.com>'

  def send_notification user_id
     ... "`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think so. It is production code and I don't own it.

Answer (score 1):

To send email to multiple users: pass an array

Replace

```
:to => user.email
```

with

```
:to => users.map(&:email)
```

more > [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#sending-email-to-multiple-recipients)

Answer (score 1):

If it is not important for you to hide email addresses from each other, you can specify recipients in a comma delimited string.