# ActionMailer sometimes not sending?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have a problem where ActionMailer sometimes doesn't send emails. It is reproducible and affects certain people at certain times, although what is causing it is a mystery.

It fails silently, although `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` is set.

It enters the mail() routine, claims it has rendered the template:

```
Rendered notifier/notify_comment.html.erb (0.9ms)
```

And then skips the delivery and moves onto the next one. The next one is rendered & delivered no problem. When emails are delivered, they are also printed to the console, so I can see it. The content of every email is the same, only the recipient is different.

I cannot understand why this would be intermittent.

How can I go about debugging this?

Comment: I would also know how to debug that. I got some troubles too, with debugging and ActionMailer. One thought: Are you calling the deliver() method after creating a mail every time? Some time ago I ran into this kind of issue

Comment: I'm running Notifier.notify_comment(@comment, current_user, @subscribers).deliver which runs once; inside it is a loop in which mail() gets called for each @subscriber.

Comment: I hope you are not handling errors using "rescue" inside your code that relates itself to the actionmailer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each instance of the mailer can only send 1 email.

Do you have code that looks like this inside of the mailer?

```
@subscribers.each do |s|
  mail(
    :to => s.email,
    :subject => "Foo Foo",
    :from => "someone@example.com", 
    :template_name => 'template_name'
  ).deliver
end
```

This doesn't seem to work. Iterate over the subscribers outside of the mailer, and call it once:

In a controller or model:

```
@subscribers.each do |s|
  Notifier.send_to_subscriber(s, @comment)
end
```

This was my experience in Rails 3.2.2. FWIW, I think what happens is that the mail object falls out of scope.

This approach may be slow, so be sure to send emails in a separate thread.

Reference and ideas: [How to send multiple emails with SendGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414506/how-to-send-multiple-emails-with-sendgrid/12992496#12992496)

Comment: Wow, you got me, that looks like it might be the problem. I'm going to quickly rewrite the code and will report back! Thanks!

Comment: FIXED! thanks, i've been staring at that for nearly 3 hours! Subtle, couldn't have done it without you!